# Exercise on ODE: Separation of Variables

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R \;$ be the solution of the
>   following ODE: $\frac{{f_x}^2}{2}=(1-f^2)^{3/2}\;$ where
>   $f_x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\;$. Find general solution $f$.

**My attempt:**
By separation of variables, I wrote:

$\frac{df}{\sqrt {2(1-f^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}}\;=\;\pm dx\;$.

I'm struggling with the above integral. How could I solve it? I tried the method of substitution but it didn't go well...I 'm lost!

**EDIT**:

Using *Wolfram Alpha* , the solution of the integral is in terms of hypergeometric function. I found this:

[image]

but I cannot make a connection to the solution.

Any suggestion would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: i think there are no Solutions in the known elementary function

Comment: According to [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt(2*(1-x%5E2)%5E(3%2F2))), the solution for the left hand side integral will contain a [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), which is a non-elementary function.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Could you explain to me what you mean by saying "in the known elementary function"? However, thanks a lot

Comment: there are other functions like $$\sin,\cos,\tan$$ and so on

Comment: @projectilemotion How will this integral be in terms of hypergeometric functions since the integral is indefinite? I 'm really new to this kind of function, so I would appreciate if you could give me more details.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, there are [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) such as $\sin$, $\cos$, $\exp$, polynomials and etc... And there are [Non-elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral) which often arise from integration problems, for example:

$$\int \frac{e^x}{x}~dx=\operatorname*{Ei}(x)+C$$

Where $\operatorname*{Ei}(x)$ is the [Exponential Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).
The integral you've obtained does not seem expressible in terms of a finite number of elementary functions.

Comment: @projectilemotion The only integrals I found which are connected to  hypergeometric functions are definite but mine isn't one of those.. Do you know how can I conclude to the solution that wolfram alpha returns back? You'd be very helpful

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get this problem from? Did you make it up yourself, or did you get it elsewhere? It will give more context to your question.

Comment: One can turn an indefinite integral into a definite one by looking at $\int_0^x F(t) \, dt$ and setting $t=xu$, so the integral is the same as $\int_0^1 xF(u/x) \, du$. This is the principle on which such hypergeometric expressions operate.

Comment: @MyGlasses Yes, finding the solution $f$ is the final goal...

Comment: There is a way to solve this ODE for $f(x)$ with an infinite series ([Power Series Solution](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SeriesSolutions.aspx)), which will be in terms of elementary functions. However, for a solution in a finite number of terms, a non-elementary integral is required.

Comment: @Chappers I think your comment is what I needed..I'm checking it right now!

Comment: @projectilemotion It's an exercise our professor gave us. He didn't mention anything more.

Comment: One can also express the solution in terms of an elliptic function. But, are you sure that this is what your professor intended? What course is it?